# putMFARequestForSite request format

Tags: yodlee

The documentation for this API is scarce to say the least, and although it says how to specify which type of MFA response is being sent, it does not say how to give the actual user response.  How do I actually send the user response?

(API documentation: https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/putMFARequestForSite )

Answer (score 0):

The putMFARequest has a little better documentation on this: https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/putMFARequest

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. The document has been updated to provide examples.
Do provide your suggestions to make it better.

[putMFARequestForSite](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/putMFARequestForSite)